# How can I create a button with a UIActivityIndicator in my navigation bar with the same style as normal buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

All of the examples I've seen on here and other sites involved creating a UIActivityIndicatorView and loading it with something like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                   initWithCustomView:myActivityIndicatorView 
                   target:nil 
                   action:nil] 
                  autorelease];
```

However, that just creates a plain activity indicator in the navigation bar. What I want to do is have a button that looks just like the normal UIBarButtonSystemItem buttons but with an activity indicator instead of one of the default images. I've tried doing initWithImage and initWithTitle with nil images or titles and then adding the activity indicator as a subview, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

My Solution is to create a subclass of UIButton:

in *SOActivityButton.h*:

```
@interface SOActivityButton : UIButton 
{
UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator;
}
@end
```

in *SOActivityButton.m*:

```
@implementation SOActivityButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        CGRect innerFrame = CGRectInset(frame, 8.0f, 8.0f);
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                    initWithFrame:innerFrame];
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        [self addSubview:activityIndicator];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [activityIndicator release], activityIndicator = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) startAnimating
{   
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void) stopAnimating
{   
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
@end
```

Then to use it:

```
SOActivityButton* activityButton = [[SOActivityButton alloc] 
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
[activityButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-background.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[activityButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) 
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *activityBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                    initWithCustomView:activityButton];
[activityButton release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityBarButtonItem;
[activityBarButtonItem release];
```

You will need to find or create a *button-background.png*. The PSD [here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2009/06/18/iphone-gui-psd-30/) should have one.

Comment: Hum, a UIBarButtonItem is not a UIButton, so your "subclass" approach should be more applied to a UIBarButtonItem directly in that case.

Comment: Not really, as UIBarButtonItem doesn't give you easy access to it's View hierarchy.  You are still going to have to create your own Views to replace UIBarButtonItem's customView, there is not much point subclassing UIBarButtonItem to do that.

Comment: This rocks a shame it hasn't been accepted as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Great code, but adding UIActivityIndicator above UIButton prevents button from getting "clicks". You should set `activityIndicator.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` as pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124301/activity-indicator-above-button-prevents-click-recognition. But maybe it wasn't like that in the time of writing this answer. I leave this comment for reference.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried creating a UIButton in the button bar and then adding an activity indicator as a subView of the UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

I have this working and it is very simple. Just place the activity indicator where you want it with IB, but make sure it's lower in the list than the bar you want it on, and is at the "top level" (not a subview of anything else). Then control it in code via an outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that can help:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
UIBarButtonItem *activityItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityItem;
[activityItem release];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: 2 times [activityIndicator startAnimating];