# Activity Indicator above Button prevents Click Recognition

Tags: xcode, button, onclick, uigesturerecognizer, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an UIButton "**bn**" and an UIActivityIndicator "**ai**" which is above the button (`ai.center = bn.center`).

As long as **ai** is visible and animating, I can't press the Button underneath **ai's** frame but out of the range I can.

Do I have to add GestureRecognition to **ai** or is there a smarter way to click on the "**ai**".

Kind regards. $h@rky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply set `ai.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`? I'm surprised it is enabled anyway, on an activity indicator - is this a standard component or have you made a subclass?

As an aside, it is usually poor UI design to have an interactive element that is covered by another view, particularly one which is used to indicate that something is "busy", but in your example of a clickable thumbnail image, it seems to make sense.

Comment: To my UIDesign. I have a set of buttons with thumbnails on them, which were load from the internet. And while this is in progress the ai is animating but you should be able to press on the button to see the fullscreen image. the button page is just a preview.
It is a standard UIActivityIndicatorView and i'm surprised too that it was enabled. Seems to be by default. Now it worked nicely. Thx.

Comment: That does make sense then. I'll amend my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the UIView method

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in the parent view. If the hit is within the button the you return the button, else you return nil. This is part of the the discussion on this method:

> This method traverses the view hierarchy by sending the
>   pointInside:withEvent: message to each subview to determine which
>   subview should receive a touch event. If pointInside:withEvent:
>   returns YES, then the subview’s hierarchy is traversed; otherwise, its
>   branch of the view hierarchy is ignored. You rarely need to call this
>   method yourself, but **you might override it to hide touch events from
>   subviews**.

EDIT:

Say you have a UIView subclass which contains bn and ai, you can implement the method like this

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bn.frame, point)) {
        return bn;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

that way your button will get the touch events (if they are within its frame) no matter if something is on top of it or not. You do not need to do anything else.

Comment: I implemented this method in nearly every class but its never called anywhere. Do I have to do maybe some additional work?

Comment: You should only implement it in the parent view, check that it gets called and determine whether the touch is over the button.

Comment: Let me resume. My button is a subview of "self.view" (UIView). So "self.view" is the parent view (=superview). So I have to subclass UIView to overwrite the method and use this "customView" as my self.view?

Comment: You could do that or just add view subclass to handle touch as a subview of the viewcontroller.view

Comment: I don't understand your "just" statement. Can you explain it a bit more, maybe with an example, too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following stuff:

First, create subclass for UIActivityIndicator with the following method override:

```
@interface MyActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicator
@end

@implementation MyActivityIndicator

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return NO;
}

@end
```

After that, use MyActivityIndicator everywhere in your project instead of UIActivityIndicator (in NIB file or in your code, depends where do you create it)

Comment: I think this will work too but "jrturton's" answer is much easier.