# Custom button in UIActivityController iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to add a custom button in the UIActivityViewController in ios6, and get its IBAction method on taping the Button. Is this possible?

Comment: Do u mean add a UIActivity?

Comment: I just need the IBAction of a button which can be added with the UIActivityViewController.

Comment: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639672/how-can-i-create-a-button-with-a-uiactivityindicator-in-my-navigation-bar-with-t

Comment: @Akhildas UIActivity is the button in UIActivityViewController, just like the facebook and twitter. You may want this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751891/problems-adding-custom-activity-to-uiactivitycontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could give you a workaround. First make a `UIView` . Then add the `UIActivityIndicator` on the View alongwith the `UIButton` in it depending on the frame you choose. In this way you would get the `IBAction` of the `UIButton` too. Hope this helps.